# Splitting equations with parentheses in aligned

Tags: math-mode, equations, align

How can I break the first line

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[2]
& some stuff \left\{ stuff' + stuff'' \right\} \\
& = some other stuff
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

in a way such that the following graphical output is obtained

```
stuff { ...
       + ... }
= some other stuff
```

for the graph parentheses, using `\right.` etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to elaborate on my comment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
 \MoveEqLeft some stuff \bigg\{ 
   \!\begin{aligned}[t] & stuff' \\
                    & + stuff'' \bigg\}
      \end{aligned}
     \\
                    & = some other stuff
\end{split}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: nice, still this code gives the third equation not aligned with the first, but a bit to the right

Comment: That is how I like it, it highlights the first line. Replace `\MoveEqLeft` with `&` and you get your ascii drawing

Comment: Right, that's what I wanted

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 some stuff \bigg\{ & stuff' \nonumber\\
                    & + stuff'' \bigg\} \\
 \makebox[\widthof{$some stuff \bigg\{$}][l]{$= some other stuff $}\nonumber
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I meant: I edited my question, perhaps now its more clear: i.e. the third line should align again with the first

Comment: @jj_p, it is still very unclear what you want. You cannot break a `\left...\right` construction over a linebreak. So where exactly is Herbert doing it wrong? To me it looks more like you want to place an additional `aligned` inside the `\{...\}`. Note in that case that the `\{` goes before the `aligned`, aligned should have an additional `[t]` option, and the `\}` goes inside the aligned.

Comment: @daleif: The only thing I can think of is that the OP wants the last line `some other stuff` to be aligned on the left in which case a `\mathclap` variant may be needed.

Comment: @PeterGrill, not really see my extended comment. Replace the `\MoveEqLeft` with a `&` and you get the ascii drawing, I just prefer this version.

Comment: @PeterGrill that's correct: can you expand on this \mathclap story?

Comment: @jj_p: See my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem you are having is that last line being longer is affecting the alignment of the lines above it.  So, you can use `mathrlap` so that the last line's length does not affect the alignment:

[image]

Note that the `=` is right aligned to the alignment point specified. This is because the usual alignment is: stuff to the left of an equal sign is right aligned, and stuff to the right of the equal is left aligned.

However, if you want the last text to be left aligned then I would recommend using an `alignedat` instead:

[image]

### Code: `aligned`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
 \text{some stuff} \bigg\{ & \text{stuff }' \\
                           & + \text{stuff }'' \bigg\} \\
 =\mathrlap{\text{some other stuff}}
\end{aligned}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

### Code: `alignedat`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
 &\text{some stuff} \bigg\{ && \text{stuff }' \\
 &                           && + \text{stuff }'' \bigg\} \\
 &=\mathrlap{\text{some other stuff}}
\end{alignedat}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this trick indeed does the business, although if the last lines (some other stuff1,2,..) are too long they might overlap with the equation number